# 2 Colors Defined In XML - Is It Possible In XML Code For One Color To Refer To The Other?

Tags: android

Say for example I define 3 colours in XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#af0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00af00</color>
    <color name="blue">#0092ed</color>
</resources>
```

Now I want to add a fourth colour which I will call 'selected_colour' and I want its value to be one of the three colours I have already defined in XML, AND I want to define this assignment in XML. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot do such thing and change its value dynamically. Instead set a static Color object in which you set the current selected color and use it whenever you want.

Comment: Correct, you wont be able to change that xml (at least, not easily) but you can instantiate that selecter_color with a default (red) by running through the XML shown in the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<color name="selected_colour">@resource/red</color>
```

You may have to repalce `@resource` with something else, but the idea itself should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> 
<color name="red">#af0000</color> 
<color name="green">#00af00</color>
<color name="blue">#0092ed</color> </resources>  <options>  <selectedColor name="red" />  </options>
```